# How can I inflate and loop views inside onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: android

This is my first time to ask a question here. I will to explain clearly what problem is.

I am creating an Android app that displays questions with choices/options in a feed. I used RecyclerView and CardView to display them. I was able to display the questions and other stuff but I am having difficulties display the options. I am trying to loop the array of options/choices inside the onBindViewHolder(). I can see in the log that the data is there but I can't/ I do not know how to add the views for the choices dynamically.

I already have the loop but I am not certain how I can I inflate or display the textviews. This is my `onBindViewHolder()` code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(PublicQuestionViewHolder publicQuestionViewHolder, int i) {
        publicQuestionViewHolder.questionAuthor.setText(questions.get(i).getQuestionAuthor());
        publicQuestionViewHolder.questionText.setText(questions.get(i).getQuestionText());

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser == questions.get(i).getQuestionParseUser()) {
            publicQuestionViewHolder.questionEditIconImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            publicQuestionViewHolder.questionEditIconImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        //Log.d("Options", String.valueOf(questions.get(i).getQuestionOptions().size()));

        if (questions.get(i).getQuestionOptions().size() != 0) {

            for (QuestionOption option : questions.get(i).getQuestionOptions()) {
                if (option.getQuestionOptionType().equals("T")) {
                    Log.d("Option", option.getQuestionOptionText());


                } else if (option.getQuestionOptionType().equals("I")) {
                    Log.d("Option", option.getQuestionOptionImage().getName());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

First get the activity context in your adapter constructor and save it.

Then just inflate that view inside onBindViewHolder like this -

```
View newView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_name, null);
```

Add that view to whichever parent you like, for eg. -

```
publicQuestionViewHolder.parentName.addView(newView);
```

Then get reference to its children like this -

```
TextView name = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: It will be called multiple times... if he scrolls and comes back.. a newView will be added again.

Comment: is there a way to avoid this? I'm in a similar situation where i need to iterate a list iniside the list and set it inside recyclerview. As you said, it's being added again when I scroll back up. I tried a crooked logic where I added the positions into a list and checking if it is already passed, but doesn't work properly.